# Authenticate LDAP user via SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, authentication, ldap, adsi

Is it possible to authenticate a user from an Active Directory through SQL Server using LDAP? Assuming that I enter the Windows domain username and password in an ADSI SQL Select query.

Comment: You can add a login to SQL Server based on a Windows account (user or group) - is that what you're looking for??

Comment: I want to user to enter his Windows Domain user and password in the program that I am working on as an added authentication. Not the one he already has in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what your desired outcome would be.

SQL 2008, AFIK, could be setup with integrated Active Directory Authentication or not.

You certainly could perform authentication via LDAP (or some other form of Authentication) to the WEB Site from AD.

And if not integrated authentication within SQL, also prompt for the credentials for SQL.

But not at all clear what your desires are.